# Ada/Gnat -- Package-level dynamic generic instantiation

Tags: generics, package, instantiation, ada, gnat

I have a generic package:

```
generic
    Size : Positive;
package Foo is

    type Unbounded_Sized_Array is Array(1..Size) of Unbounded_String;

    type My_Type is
    record
        My_Array : Unbounded_Sized_Array;
        --other stuff
    end record;

end Foo;
```

I need to declare it at package-level in another package:

```
package Bar is

    package Dynamic_Foo is new Foo(Count);

    --other stuff

end Bar;
```

The problem is I don't know what Count is until after I execute some code (it's the count of files in a given directory) and I'm not sure how I can defer the instantiation of Dynamic_Foo until after that is done. Or even if that's something that can be done in Ada. I can make a linked list type, but I'd really rather not, since the size/length should stay the same after it's initiated.

Comment: Be aware that you have a race-condition, if you first count the number of files, then declare the array, and only then read the file names into the array.

Comment: If there's a new file added at the wrong time, there could be problems. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Yes.  Or if a file is deleted at an unfortunate moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare new types and instantiate generics in any declarative region, so you can simply move the instantiation to a point where `Count` has the right value.

You could also make `Count` a function, which returns the value you need.  Then `Count` will be called where you instantiate your function, and all will be well (except for the race-condition I mentioned in my comment).

Comment: Since you mention this is a poor approach for iterating through files, I found another solution by removing the generic from the package level and making My_Type a discriminated record. Now the user assigns to My_Array directly. Accepted for offering a great solution to the general problem that will no doubt be helpful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Foo;

procedure Proc1 is
   Count : Positive := 5;
   package Foocounted1 is new Foo (Count);
   A : Foocounted1.Unbounded_Sized_Array;
begin
   Put_Line ("A'Length = " & Integer'Image (A'Length));
   Count := Count + 20;
   declare
      package Foocounted2 is new Foo (Count);
      B : Foocounted2.Unbounded_Sized_Array;
   begin
      Put_Line ("B'Length = " & Integer'Image (B'Length));
   end;
end Proc1;
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me as if you want an unbounded array of Unbounded_String. In Ada, unbounded arrays are provided by a package named, as you would expect of a pkg for unbounded arrays, Ada.Containers.Vectors:

```
package File_Lists is new Ada.Containers.Vectors (Index_Type => Positive, Element_Type => Unbounded_String);

File : File_Lists.Vector;

Get_Files : loop
   exit Get_Files when No_More_Files;

   File.Append (New_Item => Next_File);
end loop Get_Files;
```

This way there's no need to count the number of files first.